# Templates for log messages at the moment of commiting a change

Tags: svn, templates, commit, commit-message

I use Subversion.

When I try to commit a change in a repository, and forget to write a comment as part of the parameters (parameter `-m` or `--message`), a text editor opens and tells you to write a comment regarding the change.

Is there a way to add a template to the text editor, so it appears every time the editor opens at the time of commit?

Example of a template:

```
Please write down Change Request ticket number and description for changes.
Ticket: [####]
Description: [write here]
```

Comment: a bit similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983026/how-do-i-create-a-svn-commit-message-template-and-hook-to-verify?