# Eclipse SVN comment templates

Tags: eclipse, svn, comments, svncommit

Does anyone have some pointers to how to write SVN comment templates. I would like to include:

- the current date (YYYY-MM-DD)
- the author of the commit (author of the code)

Comment: Both of those are already included in the commit information, it's not necessary to repeat them in the commit message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a SVN Commit Message Template and Hook to Verify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983026/how-do-i-create-a-svn-commit-message-template-and-hook-to-verify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why you are making the change.  Try to make this something that isn't obvious from reading the code.  "fixed a typo" is preferable to changed "1 to 2".
2. If you are working on a defect, include the defect #
3. If you are working on an enhancement request or named feature or the like, include that as well.

Comment: Thanks ! I agree with you on your guidelines. My question was: how to write TEMPLATES in ECLIPSE

Comment: I wouldn't.  Because there are only two thing.  An optional identifier and a human message.  Here's how someone else did it though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983026/how-do-i-create-a-svn-commit-message-template-and-hook-to-verify.  If you are asking where they are, see preferences > svn ? templates.