# How to view Lock history in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Is there any way to view log for when file was locked in TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion doesn't store lock history.

In Apache Subversion there are things called [hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks); They are similar to triggers in SQL and perform their task *after* and *before* you perform a Subversion action on a server.

You need to take a look at the **[pre-lock](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-lock.html) and [post-lock](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-lock.html) hook script templates** which allows you to write a script to store lock history in a log file or send lock / unlock e-mail notifications.

If that template is not available in your repository you can download it from http://plugins-svn.bbpress.org/smiley-choice/hooks/pre-lock.tmpl and use it as a sample.

Remember you need to modify above template to meed your needs but this will surely help and work for you.

Please look at [How do I create a SVN Commit Message Template and Hook to Verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983026/how-do-i-create-a-svn-commit-message-template-and-hook-to-verify) also.