# pre-commit hook to mandate a pattern in commit message

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I want to mandate a specific pattern in the commit message while I commit to SVN like Defect ID. Could someone provide the shell script if you have or guide me?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated ...

Regards,
Gopal

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a SVN Commit Message Template and Hook to Verify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983026/how-do-i-create-a-svn-commit-message-template-and-hook-to-verify)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [pre-commit hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html).